# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request- ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I'm new to ASP .net core. It giving me an dependency injection error as:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Spinit.Data.Services.Repository.GameRepository' while attempting to activate 'SpinIt.Web.Controllers.CartController'. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

StackTrace is below:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

*CartController* Code

```
public class CartController:Controller
{
    private readonly GameRepository _gameRepository;
    private readonly Cart _cartRepository;

    public CartController(GameRepository gameRepository, Cart cartRepository)
    {
        _gameRepository = gameRepository;
        _cartRepository = cartRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var items = _cartRepository.GetCartItems();
        _cartRepository.CartItems = items;

        var sCVM = new CartViewModel
        {
            Cart = _cartRepository,
            CartTotal = _cartRepository.GetCartTotal()
        };
        return View(sCVM);
    }
}
```

I have also add service to *Startup.cs*

```
services.AddScoped<IGame, GameRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ICartItem, CartItemRepository>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You registered `IGame` as Service Type and `GameRepository` as implementation type with .NET Core service container in Startup.cs file. So apparently `IGame` is registered in service container and only `IGame` type can be injected through DI. DI system is not aware of service named `GameRepository` as it's not registered with DI service container.

Please make changes in controller constructor like so:

```
private readonly IGame _gameRepository;
private readonly ICartItem _cartRepository;

public CartController(IGame gameRepository, ICartItem cartRepository)
{
    _gameRepository = gameRepository;
    _cartRepository = cartRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the implementation as a constructor argument, you did not mention it on the services. Try to use the interface.

```
public class CartController:Controller
{
    private readonly IGame _gameRepository;
    private readonly ICartItem _cartRepository;

    public CartController(IGame gameRepository, ICartItem cartRepository)
    {
        _gameRepository = gameRepository;
        _cartRepository = cartRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var items = _cartRepository.GetCartItems();
        _cartRepository.CartItems = items;

        var sCVM = new CartViewModel
        {
            Cart = _cartRepository,
            CartTotal = _cartRepository.GetCartTotal()
        };
        return View(sCVM);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `GameRepository` with `IGame` and `CartItemRepository` with `ICartItem`